# How do I see which user I am logged in as on a Network Share?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-server-2003, share-credentials

IIS on my development computer (Windows 7) cannot access a windows share (Windows Server 2003), so I try to log in manually and verify that the share works for that account. **For trouble shooting purposes, how can I see which account is logged in on a Network Share?**

I try to use `net use \\server\share /u:domain\user` to verify that my IIS user can log in, but whatever i put as user (even nonexistent accounts) I get *The command completed successfully*. I suspect my personal credentials are used.

Answer (score 0):

Use `net sessions`. To access the shared folder through IIS, i think you need to do impersonate or change the default application pool user to Local user. If you are trying to access the shared folder through application hosted in IIS, then better go for windows server rather than using windows 7.